# HapiJS view file not found despite locations searched including the location of the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, hapi.js

When attempting to access my route at `localhost:82/view` I receive the following error:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: View file not found: `index.jsx`. Locations searched: [views\index.jsx]
    at Object.exports.create (C:\Git\react_playground\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\boom\lib\index.js:21:17)
    at Object.exports.internal (C:\Git\react_playground\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\boom\lib\index.js:254:92)
    at Object.exports.badImplementation (C:\Git\react_playground\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\boom\lib\index.js:290:23)
    at C:\Git\react_playground\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\vision\lib\manager.js:420:26
    at done (C:\Git\react_playground\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\items\lib\index.js:30:25)
    at C:\Git\react_playground\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\vision\lib\manager.js:415:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

My file tree is like so:

```
react_playground
|-src
| |-views
| | |-index.jsx
| |-module1.js
|-Gruntfile.js
|-...
```

You can kind of see that I'm trying to set up a livereloading workflow in Grunt (something I've never done before) but that's irrelevant to the issue. I'm concerned right now purely with why my view is unable to be found despite it searching in views\index.js.

module1.js:

```js
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var engine = require('hapi-react')();


var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({host: 'localhost',port: 82});

server.views({
  defaultExtension: 'jsx',
  path: 'views',
  engines: {
    jsx: engine, // support for .jsx files
    js: engine // support for .js
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/' ,
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    console.log('Got a request!');
    reply('Welcome to my HAPI-React Page!');
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/view',
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    reply.view('index', {
      name: 'Test'
    });
  }
});

server.start();
```

index.js:

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM **/

var React = require('react');
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

module.exports = HelloMessage;
```

Gruntfile.js:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/*.js', 'src/**/*.js']
    },
    concurrent: {
      dev: {
        tasks: ['nodemon', 'node-inspector', 'watch'],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      }
    },
    nodemon: {
      dev: {
        script: './src/module1.js',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
          env: {
            PORT: '82'
          },
          // omit this property if you aren't serving HTML files and
          // don't want to open a browser tab on start
          callback: function (nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // opens browser on initial server start
            nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
              // Delay before server listens on port
              setTimeout(function() {
                require('open')('http://localhost:82');
              }, 1000);
            });

            // refreshes browser when server reboots
            nodemon.on('restart', function () {
              // Delay before server listens on port
              setTimeout(function() {
                require('fs').writeFileSync('.rebooted', 'rebooted');
              }, 1000);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['.rebooted'],
      options: {
        livereload: true
      }
    },
    inject: {
      single: {
        scriptSrc: 'build/devscript.js',
        files: {
          // TODO: specify file to inject devScript into
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-inject');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['nodemon', 'open', 'watch']);
};
```

Comment: Can we see all your code on github?

Comment: Try adding `relativeTo: __dirname` to your views config.

Comment: Any solution you found?